# How to run Serenity BDD simple project from maven archetype (serenity.version=2.0.40)

Tags: internet-explorer, cucumber, windows-7-x64, maven-archetype, serenity-bdd

I try run simpile project from net.serenity-bdd:serenity-cucumber-archetype with Internet Explorer 11 on Winodws 7

I have many pitfalls to do this.

Try to avoid it:

1.

```
java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 2: /C:/username/Java/git_other/test/test/target/test-classes/features
```

Answer: Do not use version 2.0.42.

2.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.ie.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver. The latest version can be downloaded from http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
```

Answer: 
1.Go to page [https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/][1]
Download version 3.14.0 for (recommended) 32 bit Windows IE or 64 bit Windows IE

2.Add to %PATH% path to IEDriverServer.exe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create project:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=net.serenity-bdd -DarchetypeArtifactId=serenity-cucumber-archetype -DarchetypeVersion=1.8.4
```

Change in pom.xml:

```
<serenity.version>2.0.40</serenity.version>
<serenity.cucumber.version>1.9.33</serenity.cucumber.version>
<webdriver.driver>iexplorer</webdriver.driver>
```

Go to page https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/
Download version 3.14.0 for (recommended) 32 bit Windows IE or 64 bit Windows IE

Build the project and by happy (save you time):

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```